# Realm logOut Current user is not valid

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am call

```
SyncUser.current().logOut()
```

but when logging in (With different account) again this exception is thrown.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current user is not valid if more
>   that one valid, logged-in user exists.

This exception only happen when i am logging in with different account, for example i was logged in with some account then do log out then logging in with different account.

I tried to restart activity but same result.

What is the proper whey to log out in Realm?

I am using Google authentication with JWT.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is working only after activity restart

```
public void logOut() {

    Map<String, SyncUser> all = SyncUser.all();

    for (Map.Entry<String, SyncUser> entry : all.entrySet()) {    
        entry.getValue().logOut();
    }

}
```